# SQLite Database _id Integer Issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a simple SQLite Database in a DatabaseHelper class, which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. The database contains two columns, NAME and DESCRIPTION. Here is the method that runs in my onCreate Method within the DatabaseHelper class

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         updateMyDatabase(db, 0, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int olderVersion, int newerVersion){
    if (olderVersion<1){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE MARK (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "NAME TEXT, "
                + "DESCRIPTION TEXT);");
        insertDrink(db,"latte","Espresso and Steamed Milk");
        insertDrink(db, "cappuccino", "This a Cappuccino");
    }
}


     private static void insertDrink(SQLiteDatabase database, String name, String description){
         ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
         drinkValues.put("NAME", name);
         drinkValues.put("DESCRIPTION",description);
         database.insert("MARK",null,drinkValues);
}
```

My specific question is regarding the _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY used when the database is created. Does this number start at 1 or 0?

Here's why I'm wondering. I have a simple ListView with two items. I click the first item and pass the ListView's position, which is 0, to a different activity.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(position){
                case 0:{
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
                    i.putExtra(Details.EXTRA_DRINKNUM,(int)id);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
                    i.putExtra(Details.EXTRA_DRINKNUM,(int)id);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I then retrieve this number within that Activity and place it in a variable called clickNum.

I then use clickNum to query the database:

```
        SQLiteOpenHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("MARK",
                new String[]{"NAME","DESCRIPTION"},
                "_id = ?",
                new String[]{Integer.toString(clickNum)},
                null,null,null);
```

I can ONLY pull up my first row containing the of data (Latte ....) if I do drinkNum + 1. Why is that? Shouldn't the first row _id be 0???

Here is a more detailed look at the class (Details) that queries the database:

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView name, description;
public static final String EXTRA_DRINKNUM = "DrinkNum";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsCoffeeName);
    description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsCoffeeDescription);

    int clickNum = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNUM);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("DESCRIPTION", "Lateeeee");

    try{
        SQLiteOpenHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("MARK",
                new String[]{"NAME","DESCRIPTION"},
                "_id = ?",
                new String[]{Integer.toString(clickNum)},
                null,null,null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
            String descriptionText = cursor.getString(1);

            name.setText(nameText);
            description.setText(descriptionText);
        }else{
            Log.v("Details", "Nothing Found");
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Database Issue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: You have a bug in your app: you are assuming that the `ListView` `position` has any relationship whatsoever to the `_ID` value. These generally will not match, either due to database manipulation (e.g., deleting a row) or app manipulation (e.g., sorting the results). Use the `_ID` value itself, please. For example, the `long id` passed into your item-click listener is `_ID`, and `getItemId()` on `CursorAdapter` will give you the `_ID` for a given `position`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't more clear, Yes, in my itemClickListener, I pass  a long id on to the next activity. I retrieve it there in a variable called clickNum and then use that to query the database. My issue is that the long id that I pass, for instance 0 for the first item does not bring up the first row of my database. It only brings up the first row if I add a 1 to the long id that I passed (clickNum + 1). Is that because the Database's AutoIncrement begins at 1 and not 0?

Comment: "Is that because the Database's AutoIncrement begins at 1 and not 0?" -- no. Where is `clickNum` coming from in your `Integer.toString(clickNum)`? Are you really sure that's coming from `Details.EXTRA_DRINKNUM`?

Comment: I added more of the class which contains the query. The clickNum is coming from this line of code :int clickNum = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNUM);

Comment: Are you using `CursorAdapter`? Or when you query the database, are you pouring your data into something else (e.g., array of POJOs) that you are using with another sort of adapter (e.g., `ArrayAdapter`)?

Comment: Nope, I'm just taking my data and placing it in to two TextViews. I added the remainder of the class above so you can see.

Comment: Huh? You have a `ListView`. There is an adapter in it. I thought that the adapter was populated from the database. If it is not, then there is no *a priori* relationship whatsoever between anything in the `ListView` (`position`, `id`, whatever) and the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases's Auto Increment starts at 1. :)